# Tour contains bad comment example

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, comments, tour-page

The Tour has the following explanation about comments:

> Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer.

…but then the accompanying screenshot shows a comment that does neither of those things, and is in fact chatty/delete-worthy:

[image: Screenshot in "improve posts by editing or commenting" section of the Tour, with excellent freehand red circle]

Is this the best visual example we can use here?

Comment: a feature request to get rid of garbage like that: [Hide comments (if there are any) in the example posts selected for the Tour page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315594/165773) at MSE: "...The last but not the least, showing comments in examples tends to dilute the site purpose promised right at the top of the tour page: _'Ask questions, get answers, no distractions'_ (this is particularly prominent in the example from TWP meta linked above, where comment is essentially an attempt at answer and is presented about as important as the post above it)."

Comment: @gnat I'm not suggesting removing or hiding anything, just to have a better example of a comment in this specific instance.

Comment: the point of mentioned FR is that comments in tour examples are superfluous and inherently risky so that there is no need to show these at all. Wrt better examples, as explained over there expecting this is unrealistic "there is no way for site community to help system find out whether particular comment is a poor fit for the tour. This means that examples may show inappropriate comments that just randomly gained a few popularity upvotes... Nor would it be fair to expect of site community to pay same attention to comments as it does to questions and answers..."

Comment: @gnat I disagree. People are misusing comments (e.g. answers in comments) all over the place. Good examples absolutely should be part of the tour. Otherwise, well, what's the point of it?

Comment: I would be the first to agree with your disagreement if you explain how to realistically distinguish say, tangential joke with handful random upvotes from an important request to clarify the question

Comment: @gnat As such an experienced user of this network I'm sure you've come across comments that suggest or request clarifications from a post, and so I'm sure I don't need to find any examples for you!

Comment: do I understand it correctly that you suggest manual picking of comments for tour examples?

Comment: @gnat Are you suggesting that the Tour is auto-generated from arbitrary posts on every page visit? If so, that's both insane and really easy to fix. Yes, _of course_ you should hand-pick examples of the sort of posts you want people to learn how to write. I'll note, though, that every time I go to the Tour I get the same content.

Comment: Anyway, I don't really care how it's implemented: I care about the outcome.

Comment: selection is automatic as [explained eg here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245017/165773)

Comment: I wonder what thought process led to that decision.

Comment: Also, @gnat, the page you link to explains that there is a manual override...

Comment: yeah, and I understand how it works for regular questions and answers, mod overrides are expected to handle rare cases when inappropriate posts leaked through regular community moderation of votes down and close. For comments, community can't do such "natural pre-moderation", does that mean mods would need to check and override all the comments in selected examples?

Comment: @gnat I say just make the Tour a normal, conventional, typical webpage (like the good old days?) with proper, reliable examples of what we want to see on the site. Honestly how hard can that be

Comment: As a temporary workaround, it's possible to manually review the tour page and delete the bad comments via flags (on the actual comment), and wait for the page to update...

Comment: @gnat "all"? What prevents us from having only one good example for the tour?

Comment: @user202729 if MSO folks make enough noise whining to force SE team replace automatic selection of Tour examples with manual that would be awesome (I believe it is the only meta site capable to make enough push to move the mountain of indifference of SE team in cases like that). In the meantime, while examples are (still) picked automatically, stripping off comments appears to be the most reasonable and necessary thing to do

Comment: @gnat: I suppose, given what I have learned here about how the Tour is constructed, I can support that as the quickest temporary workaround.

Comment: And "comments are not to be used for extended discussions". Suits well on this question I believe :-)

Comment: In case anyone needs it, this is the link to the [tour].

Comment: @Andreas many of main site quality norms don't apply to meta, see eg beautiful explanation of why this is so in [What is a meta for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240440/165773) This is particularly true for discussions in comments

Comment: @gnat it was a joke. Jokes are usually visible in written form as they accompanyied with a combination of two or three ASCII characters like `:-)` or `:)`

Comment: the answer isn't that good either. It's borderline comment.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No, that's definitely an answer and should absolutely not be written in the comments section. Could it be a longer, more fleshed-out answer? Possibly.

Comment: you're right, but I would not vote for that one

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's fine :) (Although, _personally_, I think the answer is spot-on and I'm not sure what more information there is to give. The question's pretty narrow.)

Comment: maybe it's made to be understood easily. A 2-page C++ answer with references to the standard isn't as clear as an example :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There's some added detail [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24010399/560648) that arguably should have been edited into the answer, which may have made it better. It could do with some cross-references/citations, too, despite the apparent authority of the author.

Comment: I don't understand why they have a big red circle on the tour page :p

Comment: @YvetteColomb Teaching people to draw freehand red circles is obviously the most important aspect of the tour :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention.

This has now been sorted out.